# Math competition problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've came across this task week ago on our university math competition (which was selecting people for uni math team). As far as I know this task was solved by small amount of people, unfortunately excluding me..
For some reason there won't be any solutions published in the nearest future and I want to understand how it was thought to be solved.

Task is following:

[2 points] a) Assuming that Random Variable $X$ has symmetric distribution, such as Pr($X=x$)=Pr($X=-x$) and Random Variable $Y$ takes values 1 and -1 with equal probabilities (0.5). Prove that Random Variables $X$ and $X \cdot Y$ have the same distribution (talking about probability distribution ofc). [was said, that this point was the easiest of two]

[4 points] b) Random Variables $X, Y, Z, W$ are mutually independent and distributed similarly: every variable takes either $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability (0.5). Are mutually independent following Random Variables: $XYZ, XYW, XW$?

Would appreciate any idea/solution

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Sorry, I’m less than a year on this forum.. however this points seem to be related in some way, so maybe they are not that distinct

Comment: So (a) is false as written.  Did you want to assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, X and Y are independent;
It may be, that it is false, however further explanations are needed.. Here word “Proof” doesn’t necessarily means that it is true :)

Comment: Here are two nice answers when the distribution is normal. Note that the same thinking works with any symmetric distribution instead. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27097/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-product-of-a-bernoulli-a-normal-random-variabl/27145

Answer (score 1):

For (a), note that
$XY \leq x$ if $X \leq x$ and $Y = 1$ or if $X \geq -x$ and $Y = -1.$
From these facts, compute $P(XY \leq x).$
Compare it to $P(X \leq x).$

For (b), all those variables and their products make my head hurt,
so I just assumed $X = 1$ and made a table of all possible values of
$Y,$ $Z,$ and $W$ and the resulting values of $XYZ,$ $XYW,$ and $XW.$
I used this table to show that each of the eight possible values of the
ordered triple $(XYZ,XYW,XW)$ occurs with probability $1/8$ when $X=1.$
It is obvious that they also each occurs with probability $1/8$ when $X=-1.$
Therefore they each occur with probability $1/8.$

Comment: Not sure how you're using the CDF but simply if we define z=xy then P(Z=x) = (X=x)(Y=1)+(X=-x)(Y=-1) which = x given the bernoulli of y and note the same for P(Z=-x) is also x hence the distribution is also symmetrical, again assuming rv independence.

Comment: @mathcompguy I was considering the possibility that $X$ could have a continuous or mixed distribution. If it is purely discrete then I would have no objection to using the mass function rather than the CDF.

Comment: @DavidK and is it enough in point $(a)$ to compare it in one way with $x$? Don't we need to do symmetric comparison "$>x$"?

Comment: The cumulative distribution function, which identifies the distribution of a random variable, is defined by a one-way comparison. Once you know the CDF is the same for each variable you know the distribution is the same. So no, we do not need to do a symmetric comparison.